# Finding a quicker method to construct a matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to construct a (p+1,n) matrix with the code below:

```
import numpy as np

p = 3
xh = np.linspace(0.5,1.5,p+1)
n = 7
x = np.linspace(0,2,n)

M = np.zeros([p+1,n])
l2 = 1

for i in range(len(x)):
    for k in range(len(xh)):
        for j in range(len(xh)):
            if k != j:
                l = (x[i]-xh[j])/(xh[k]-xh[j])
                l2 *= l
            elif k == j:
                l = 1
                l2 *= l
        M[k][i]=l2
        l2 = 1 
print(M)
```

This method produces the matrix I want but is very slow (6 sec for p=40 and n=2000).

The matrix itself is a matrix of lagrange polynomials, for approximating some function. The nodal points, xh, are the points used in forming/calculating the interpolation of a function. They have the property that their values on the original function and the interpolation are always the same. The number of distinct nodal points (p+1) indicate the degree (p) of the polynomial for the Lagrange interpolation. The x points are where a function is to be evaluated. That could be the interpolation of the function or the function. This is the formula I'm following:

[image]

I don't know how a faster way to construct a matrix in numpy, other methods seem to keep going wrong when I apply it to the code I've got and I don't know enough to see why. What faster method can I use here?

Comment: I suggest describing what "the matrix I want" is. You cannot expect people to reverse-engineer what your code is doing.

Comment: I suspect the key is to think of writing the `j` loop in a different way, one that doesn't require the `i!=j` test.  Maybe do the same thing for all `j` (i.e. the whole dimension), and subtract the `i==j` case.  If you can get rid of that iteration, the rest will be a whole-array calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be nicely compiled by decorating a function with [`@nb.njit`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/performance-tips.html) from the [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/) package. Some minor redundant parts were removed.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def test(p,n):
    xh = np.linspace(0.5,1.5,p+1)
    x = np.linspace(0,2,n)
    M = np.zeros((p+1,n), dtype=nb.float64)
    l2 = 1

    for k in range(len(x)):
        for i in range(len(xh)):
            for j in range(len(xh)):
                if i != j:
                    l = (x[k]-xh[j])/(xh[i]-xh[j])
                else:
                    l = 1
                l2 *= l
            M[i][k]=l2
            l2 = 1 
    return M
```

Benchmark for `p=40, n=2000` on a 2-core colab instance. Array *M* was computed with your original code.

```
a = [0]
%timeit a[0] = test(40,2000)
np.testing.assert_allclose(M, a[0])
```

Runs in `5.57 ms per loop vs 2.24 s per loop` or ~402x speed up.